# Updating an array field that contains hashes in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have a document in `XYZ` collection as follows.

```
"_id" : ObjectId("55311e4487216d7063040000"),
"colours" : [
    {
         "value" : 1,
         "colour" : "red"
    },
    {
         "value" : 2,
         "colour" : "green"
    }
]
```

I need to update the name of the colour which value is 1. What query should I write?

I am using rails 4.1.2, mongoid 4.0.0.

Please help.

Comment: Yes, `colours` is an array type inside a collection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example you want to change it to "yellow" :

```
XYZ.where(_id: "55311e4487216d7063040000").elem_match(colours: { value: 1 }).update("$set" => {"colours.$.colour" => "yellow"})
```